# Is it correct to walk through QMap with iterators and erasing/adding items?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

Is it correctly possible to walk sequently through QMap with help of iterators, and doing such actions: removing some items and adding new ones?

For example:

```
for( QMap<key_t,val_t>::iterator it = map.begin();
     it != map.end();
     ++it )
{
     if( it->value == something )
     {
          map.erase(it);
          map.insert(it->key+10,it->value); 
     } 
}
```

It seems, that nothing will be done wrong, I'm asking to be sure. (I have no enough time to check it).

**UPD** Will solve with `QMap::unite()`:

```
for( QMap<key_t,val_t>::iterator it = map.begin();
     it != map.end();
     ++it )
{
     if( it->value == something )
     {
          tmp_map.insert(it->key+10,it->value); 
          map.erase(it);
     } 
}
map.unite(tmp_map);
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it a little while... You are iterating over a collection, removing an item in the middle and adding another item somewhere else. Will the iterators still be correct? Will the "next" iterator really be the next item?

In general it is not a good idea to change a collection you are iterating over. If you need to then use a temporary collection and copy selected items over to that, and clear the real collection and move the items from the temporary collection over to the real one.

<s>In your case though, why not use `QMap::find` to search for `something`, and if found erase it and add the new item, and do it in a loop until `something` is not found anymore?</s>

Comment: Thank you for useful answer! I cannot use your advice in last sentence because I should manipulate with item of QMap looking to its value. After erasing and inserting value doesn't change, so I may operate with the same items infinitely. I've took into account your advice to use a temporary collection and solve the problem with QMap::unite(). Thank a lot!

Answer (score 14):

The iterator will be invalidated by `erase`, and so cannot safely be used or incremented afterwards. The following should work:

```
for( QMap<key_t,val_t>::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ) 
{
    if( it->value == something ) 
    {
        map.insert(it.key()+10,it.value()); 
        it = map.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would expect `it` to be invalid after `map.erase(it)`, in which case `it->value` and `++it` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to 'reset' your iterator to the one returned by `erase` and `insert`.  It's fine in principle though.